# Possible to create columns in form dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Anyone know of a solution to create aligned columns in form dropdown list?

Perhaps with css

Cross browser would be handy ... 
e.g.

```
<select size="1">
<option> John Smith      | 24 | United States</option>
<option> Johnny Vegas    | 34 | United Kingdom</option>
<option> Andrew Townsend | 34 | Canada</option>
</select>
```

The vertical bars are just representation of the column aligns ..

Hope that makes sense

Comment: You're probably better off using a custom combo-box control instead of the browser built-in if you want clean multi-column functionality.  There are a handful of custom libraries that implement such a thing.

Comment: You should have to use your own customize dropdown created by divs or other HTML elements. and define it's events by JavaScript to make it look like fancy drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gdoron got me thinking so I wrote a quick PHP hack for those finding this thread later

```
$name = str_replace("_", "&nbsp;", str_pad($name , 50 ,"_"));
```

I'm sure theres other ways to do this in php..

Pretty sure this would work cross browser off to test!

Make sure you style the

```
select style="font-family: monospace;"
```

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done with css, you can add white spaces to indent it, just like you did with the question.

```
<select size="1">
    <option> John Smith &thinsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; &thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;  | 24 | United States</option>
    <option> Johnny Vegas&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp; &thinsp;| 34 | United Kingdom</option>
    <option> Andrew Townsend | 34 | Canada</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7sUqq/)

Comment: You'll probably want a fixed-width font as well.

Comment: You make a good point.. however the data is dynamic from a database so I wont know the lengths.. You think I could be done with PHP?

Comment: @Webby. It can be done on the client side or the server side, each way is o.k.

Comment: Thanks upvoted! this helped me create a solution with php.. see answer

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this, if you're wary of adding additional requests to your page loads in the form of a library, is to use CSS to create a ul-li visible custom drop-down and attach click events to each li to manipulate a hidden select. It's fairly easy to do using CSS and jQuery / javascript (I prefer jQuery simply because it's less typing and I'm used to it).